# How to save multiple vectors into list to return in R

Tags: r, list

I need to generate following example:

```
month=12
n=1
output=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]

month=12
n=2
output=[[1,3,5,7,9,11],[2,4,6,8,10,12]]

month=12
n=3
output=[[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]
```

I tried but failed

```
v=function(a){
  b=12/a
  c=12%%a
  d=seq(1,12,a)
  e=seq(0,a)
  f=list()
  for (i in 0:a)
  {
    #f.append(e[i]+d)
  }
  
  return(f)
}


v(3)
```

Here is the code I have, but I don't know how to store vector into two dimensional list. Can you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` should give what your want:

```
v <- function(n, month = 12) {
  month <- seq_len(month)
  res <- split(month, factor((month - 1) %% n))
  unname(res)
}

str(v(1)) 
#List of 1
# $ : int [1:12] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

str(v(2))
#List of 2
# $ : int [1:6] 1 3 5 7 9 11
# $ : int [1:6] 2 4 6 8 10 12

str(v(3))
#List of 3
# $ : int [1:4] 1 4 7 10
# $ : int [1:4] 2 5 8 11
# $ : int [1:4] 3 6 9 12
```